# Source Tree: remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for '**MYURL**'

Tags: git, github, version-control

I tried to clone, pull, or push in source tree and this error comes out.

When I tried to do it in the command line I can do the following code. What seems to be the issue in source tree here?

Comment: Are you using ssh keys? Have you told SourceTree about those keys so that it can use it?

Comment: No I am not using ssh keys @zero298

Comment: Maybe you have to disable "Two Factor Authentication" or create a Access Token...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this answer: [Sourcetree remote: Invalid username or password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622960/sourcetree-remote-invalid-username-or-password)

But is not quite the same solution. Go to

```
Tools > Options > Git > Embed
```

Then:

```
1. Do the above.
2. Close Sourcetree
3. Delete AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\passwd 
4. Restart SourceTree
5. Hurray!!!
```

It's fixed for me.. maybe problems with the current version.

Answer (score 3):

In case of Github + 2FA here is the solution:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

"Once you have a token, you can enter it instead of your password when performing Git operations over HTTPS."

So for Sourcetree mac v4.0.2 -> go to preferences -> Accounts -> Add\Edit -> choose Github -> Auth Type: Basic -> Protocol:HTTPS -> put your token as the password:)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting my github account and adding it again solved the issue for me:
OSX > Preferences > Account > Remove account > Add account