# Can't clone a repository using Sourcetree

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to setup Sourcetree from scratch, I created Sourcetree and Bitbucket accounts, created a new Bitbucket repository and trying to clone it. But 'checking source" newer ends and I see a popup "CredentialHelperSelector", what should I do with it?

[image]

I tried following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622960/sourcetree-remote-invalid-username-or-password#_=_):

1. Tools > Options > Git > Update Embedded Git - I made this
2. I couldn't do the Latisha's answer part because there is no Atlassian folder in my AppData\Local\

Comment: And what happens if you select one "Credential Helper", as example *wincred* (most famous for me)?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen The popup disappears, and then appears again in a few seconds

Comment: A credential helper helps to provide a username and its password to http/https repository URLs, so the user does not have to manually enter the username and password every time. If set, it caches the username and password for a period of time or permanently. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Answer (score 7):

For Windows, you should select "manager-core", then enter your credentials (Bitbucket user account name and password).

Then your credentials would be cached and would not be asked again next time you open SourceTree and try to push to your remote repository.

Comment: Thank you, I clicked manager-core, the popup disappear, but repository check now shows the following error: "Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks ls-remote <repository link here>
Output: 
Error: fatal: unable to access '<repository link here>': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Comment: @Rumata Are you on Windows, and what remote repository hosting service are you trying to reach? github.com?

Comment: yes, on Windows. I just created a new empty repository in bitbucket for testing sourcetree, and stuck here at the beginning not being able to clone it.

Comment: @Rumata What URL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Using SourceTree 3.4.8 installed on a clean Windows 11 in a virtual machine, I get the credential helper selection dialog.

I found out that selecting "manager-core" from the list and checking always use was the solution. If the popup comes again, selecting the second option "manager-core" was definitive. I don't know why there are several options with the same name, but the second one was the solution.

Also since I was cloning a repository (with https) from bitbucket, I also had to connect to my account in Tools > Options > Authentication > Add > select HTTPS and OAuth, Refresh OAuth Token.